# Calculate the time for a function to fall below a number

Tags: matlab

I am pretty new to MatLab and I recently have been looking into Brownian Motion and applying it to stochastic population dynamics. I am trying to calculate the average time it takes for values to fall below a threshold value. Specifically, to hit 1 or below because at that point a population would surely go extinct.

The code I have to generate this data outputs a graph with function trajectories over time, given a specified number of time-steps and iterations. Is there some way to calculate time to reach this number for each of my trajectories, in order for me to then take an average?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. I can provide my codes if relevant. Thank you in advance!

My code is as follows:

```
function [x] = myBrownianMotion3(N, nPaths)
% N         = number of steps
% nPaths    = number of paths

 x = zeros(nPaths,N);

 dt = 0.1;
 sdt = sqrt(dt);

 x(:,1) = 10*ones(nPaths,1); %initial population sizes are 10
 t(1) = 0;

    for n = 1:N

         a = randn(nPaths,1)*sdt;
        % a = sign(randn(nPaths,1))*sdt; %sign of a normally
        %                distributed random number
        %                returns -1, 0, or 1

        mu = 0;
        sig = 0.2*x(:,n);
        x(:,n+1) = x(:,n) + mu*dt + sig.*a; %adds new value to current location
        t(n+1) = t(n) + dt; %time dep on steps
    end
plot(t,x)
xlabel('Time'), ylabel('Population size'), title('Stochastic Population Model')

end
```

=======

Now, I know this grabs the endpoints:

```
A = myBrownianMotion3(n, nPaths);
A(:,end);
B = A(:,end);
```

But I do not see how to calculate the actual time to fall below 1. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I didn't add an example because I do not know how to approach my problem in MatLab (as of yet).

Comment: You need to show us what you have so far, so we can help with pointing out specific issues in your code. Stackoverflow is for helping with concrete programming related questions, e.g. if you're running into a compiler error, unexpected behavior you can't seem to fix or other concrete issues in your code. Of course we also try to help beginners when they are stuck in a specific task, but we need at least the code you tried to come up with. Because if you have nothing, it feels like we're doing your work for you. Hope you understand!

Comment: Unfotunately "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Given `A` the output of your `myBrownianMotion3`, and `K` the threshold number, here is how to proceed:

```
t_fall = A < K;
t_fall = sum(cumprod(~t_fall,2),2) + 1;
t_fall(t_fall == size(A,2) + 1,:) = NaN;
```

Let's make a concrete example:

```
A = myBrownianMotion3(200,25); % 200 Steps % 25 Paths
K = 1; % Threshold 1

t_fall = A < K;
t_fall = sum(cumprod(~t_fall,2),2) + 1;
t_fall(t_fall == size(A,2) + 1,:) = NaN;
```

One of the possible outcomes could be, for example:

```
t_fall = [
   NaN;
   NaN;
   167;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   111;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   NaN;
   98
];
```

which means that only `3` paths fall below the specified threshold `K=1`: the `3rd` one at `t=167`, the `13th` one at `t=111` and the `last` one at `t=98`.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much! I was looking for some sort of function to do exactly this. So I understand that cumprod() will compute products along the rows, but would you mind explaining what you did in the line 

t_fall = sum(cumprod(~t_fall,2),2) + 1;

Comment: Sure! You make a row-wise cumulative product by rows on the inverse of the logical indexer. This means that as long as one `0` is found, all what follows will be equal to `0`.. The row-wise sum of that (plut `1` because you want indices that, in Matlab, are one-based) will tell how many consecutive good values (above threshold) there are.